# Prevent file from being modified or deleted even by chattr

Tags: linux

Is there a way to prevent anyone from deleting or modifying a file even with chattr.

For example: If I use chattr +I on a file. And another root user or the same root user uses chattr -I they'd be able to modify/delete the file. Is there a way for this not to happen.

Comment: You could possibly make a kernel module that exposes the data in /proc/some-file, which then would be mostly/entirely untouchable in user space.

Comment: I guess you actually mean the lower case `i` (immutable attribute)?

Answer (score 1):

No, a `root` user is like an Administrator on Windows, he can do anything, or almost. Just like a local Windows Administrator can delete any file from anyone if he really wants to, so can user `root` on Linux.